# TagReadWithGene missing when using latest version of Drop-seq_tools

Tags: scrnaseq, gene

I am using [Drop-seq_tools](http://mccarrolllab.org/dropseq/) to analyze scRNA-seq in a similar way of [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29227469). I am using the [same data (GSE97930)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE97930) to get used to Drop-seq_tools.

On the GEO repo the authors provide the relevant code ([GSE97930_README.txt](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/download/?acc=GSE97930&format=file&file=GSE97930%5FREADME%2Etxt)). However, one tool used in the script is missing: **TagReadWithGene**.

The latest version of Drop-seq_tools does not have such method (as it should be provided by this library), and there is no version history for the whole package, so I cannot download previous versions.

The best matches for the missing method are **TagReadWithGeneExon** and **TagReadWithInterval**.
In the methods of the cited paper they say:

> Reads that mapped to intronic or exonic regions of genes as per the GENCODE gene annotation were recorded.

I think that in this case the tool to use should be **TagReadWithInterval** since the other one should consider only exons.

I cannot find any other documentation about the tools. Do you know/already encountered this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this response](https://github.com/broadinstitute/Drop-seq/issues/38#issuecomment-424833407) from Drop-seq_tools team, at the moment intronic regions cannot be annotated and **TagReadWithGeneExon** should be used instead.

However, in the version of the [public repository](https://github.com/broadinstitute/Drop-seq):

> TagReadWithGeneExonFunction is the old code, for people who want the more simple tagging methodology and rely on it for 3rd party tools, and TagReadWithGeneFunction, which for your purposes replaces TagReadWithGeneExon. [...]  You’ll see additional options to extract expression for CODING, UTR, INTRONIC reads [...]